# PHPMailer: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

When I send a request to this, the request times out. This code has worked on another script in the same directory. I just logged into the gmail via browser to make sure all was good. The logged value of `$mail->ErrorInfo` is: `SMTP connect() failed.`

Any idea why this might work back in November but now throws an error when I copy it to another script?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx');
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx');
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->Subject = 'Your License Information';
$mail->Body = $message;
```

I tried another gmail account and I've tried using the app password Gmail gives you.

Comment: You should use the debug option, also are you using your gmail account password or an app password?

Comment: Oops, just saw `$mail->ErrorInfo` bit, create an app password and use that https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I tried that but this is the only app on the page: http://i.imgur.com/S1IoI8Y.png

Comment: Here is what shows when I click `view all` in the image above: http://i.imgur.com/Z11PENB.png

Comment: Just visit the link above, create a Mail app password and then use that instead of your standard password. Its not a permission thing its a set and forget password

Comment: The first link is what is shown...

Comment: No the first image is https://myaccount.google.com/ page!

Comment: Correct, it redirects there.

Comment: You should see this page, http://i.imgur.com/d3o8yyR.png if you cant access it then i cant help you any further

Comment: I see. So enable 2-step verification?

Comment: **Its not a permission thing its a set and forget password**, dude just create a Mail password (custom name on second dropdown) and use that before you ask another question try it!

Comment: **The first thing your screenshot says is** `App passwords allow 2-step verification users to access their google accounts through apps such...` I think that clearly implies this is a permission thing and I need 2-step verification enabled

Comment: If you're going to start **bolding** things and getting excited, at least be certain in what you're preaching, otherwise say it in a nice matter

Comment: Im trying to help you, nevermind

Comment: Yeah, you were until you started yelling. Anyways, I'll enable 2-step and give that a try and report back for future readers.

Comment: Okay. Doing 2-step authentication and using one of the passwords given did not work.

Comment: You're probably running into [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/350), which is covered in [the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: @Synchro that helped a lot. It was a local nameserver issue. As your link said, `"it's almost always down to local DNS failure, firewall blocking or other issue on your local network"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had it working before in same directory with similar code, I knew it had to be something weird. I tried `ping google.com` which didn't work and got me thinking about outbound traffic. Then I did `ping 24.156.131.93` which is Google's IP (cutting out the domain resolver) and that worked, so I changed my nameservers in resolv.conf to Google's `8.8.8.8` and it now works. So basically, my host has some issues with their nameservers they provided, and the error wasn't just for SMTP but outgoing traffic is a whole.